# Unexplained Data Enable Pin

Tags: microcontroller, spi, interface

Looking at [This](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/1e/3f/2a/d6/25/eb/48/46/DM00103319.pdf/files/DM00103319.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00103319.pdf) 
datasheet for the [LSM9DS1TR](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/LSM9DS1TR/497-14946-1-ND/4988079) 9-axis IMU, there is a pin labeled DEN_A/G with the description "Accelerometer and gyroscope data enable" on page 11.

I can find no further explanation for this pin other than **Figure 15 LSM9DS1 electrical connections** (Page 27) which shows that DEN_A/G is an input. This is not the chip select pin; there is another pin, CS_A/G, for that already.

The Data Enable pin is not mentioned anywhere in the interfacing portion of the document (Section 5 on page 28). I plan on using this with SPI.

What should a data enable pin do? Does it need to be connected to a digital pin on my micro controller? Could I leave it with no connection? Or should it be directly connected to ground or VDD?

Comment: I found this post here asking the same question which appears to be answered, however it's functionality appears to be somewhat complex and I don't know the details of the chip enough to sum this up in an answer.
https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkhX7SAJ/what-does-the-denag-pin-on-the-lsm9ds1-actually-do

Comment: It doesn't look answered to me.  I see a guess by someone who hasn't used the chip.  If you go to the ST page for the device, there is an evaluation board, and the pin is broken out on it, but I can't find out what it does for sure.  This would be enough to send me to another chip.

Comment: @KevinBrant I have to say I agree with Scott Seidman. There was an attempt at an answer, but the register they mention (0x11h) they refer to by the name *DEN Register Configuration.* In the datasheet, 0x11h is called CTRL_REG2_G, and the uppermost three bits are explicitly 0s in the datasheet (Pg 47), not  <Edge_Sens_EN, Level_Sens_EN_, Level2_Sens_EN> as the answerer mentions in that forum.

Comment: I see, my mistake then. I will leave the comment as I think the page still may contain some useful information.

Comment: The [application note AN5125](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5125-ism330dlc-3d-accelerometer-and-3d-gyroscope-with-digital-output-for-industrial-applications-stmicroelectronics.pdf) explains the use of this pin in detail.

Comment: (The above comment was converted from a link-only answer. The linked appnote is for a different device than the one in the original question. However... On a quick review, some of the functionality described in that appnote (even though it's for a different device) _seems_ similar to the undocumented functionality being asked about in the question. Therefore, rather than deleting the link-only answer outright, it has been moved to here, in case someone with time to investigate further can find some relevant value in it.)

Answer (score 3):

According to Miroslav Batek, an ST employee who has posted a number of responses about Magnetometers to the ST forum, this pin can be left unconnected if bits 5-7 are left as 0 in CTRL_REG2_G as recommended in the datasheet.

He confirms the response of Petr S O who describes if any of those bits are set to 1, then the DEN_A/G pin can be used as an input pin in one of three modes (Edge, Level, Pulse [100,010,011]) to trigger a reading to be sent only on this pin changing state in various ways. This is described somewhat unclearly and not at all in the datasheet, and the general consensus seems to be to leave DEN_A/G floating and, as recommended in the data sheet, leave bits 7-5 all zero.

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkhX7SAJ/what-does-the-denag-pin-on-the-lsm9ds1-actually-do